# Can any bipartite state be written as $\rho_{AB}=\sum_{ij} p_{ij}\rho_A^i\otimes \rho_B^j$?

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, density-operator

I'm having a silly doubt. If $\rho_{AB}$ is separable then we can write it as
$$ \rho_{AB}=\sum_i p_i\rho_A^i\otimes \rho_B^i$$
but can we write a general (maybe entangled) state as $$ \rho_{AB}=\sum_{ij} p_{ij}\rho_A^i\otimes \rho_B^j$$?

Comment: Do you require that the rho are positive?

Answer (score -1):

Of course you can do that. In fact, the first expression you wrote, which is a very special case of the second formula, is called the [Schmidt decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schmidt_decomposition). The Schmidt decomposition form is not unique to separable states and any density matrix can be written in that form. The number of terms in the Schmidt decomposition, AKA Schmidt rank, is a useful measure for distinguishing entangled states from simply separable states:

$$\mathrm{Schmidt\ rank = 1} \Leftrightarrow \mathrm{State \ is\ a \ product \ state.} $$

Comment: Given the question, it is most likely that the rho are positive.

Comment: For mixed states, the statement "Schmidt rank = 1 <=> separable" is plain wrong.  Schmidt rank 1 is equivalent to a product state.  Mixed separable states, however, can be classically correlated.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch I see, "separable" has a somewhat different meaning in the context of density matrices. As you pointed out, I really meant to write product state, aka "simply separable state".

Comment: *"distinguishing entangled states from simply separable states"* is still incorrect.